# testing http.get() with qunit in node.js

Tags: node.js, qunit

I'm trying to write a simple qunit test for a node.js library, code.js. The first test case is the simplest one i'm trying and doesn't use any exported function in my code.js library, but it doesn't work.

The QUnit module is as follows:

```
module = QUnit.module

var = http.require('http');

test("client test", function(){
    expect(1);
    var options = {
        host: 'www.google.es',
        port: 80,
        path: '/'
    }
    http.get(options, function(res){
        ok(true, "http.get callback success");
    });
});
```

I think that one of the problems is that the test execution finish before the get callback gets executed, but i'm not really sure. Maybe the rest of the problems are that i'm a beginner with qunit, so i'll really apreciate any comments.

Solution: I will use an asyncTest:

```
asyncTest("client test", function(){
    expect(1);
    var options = {
        host: 'www.google.es',
        port: 80,
        path: '/'
    }
    http.get(options, function(res){
        ok(true, "http.get callback success");
        start();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest, this API appears to be an afterthought, but I think you're looking for `asyncTest` rather than test

https://github.com/kof/node-qunit/blob/master/test/api.js#L107-115

Not a fan of this module.

Comment: Certainly, I needed to use asyncTest, i've tried it before but not in the right way. So, to succesfully write an async test with QUnit, MUST call start() after the assertion. I'll edit my question to post the working code.